# Graphql Introspection result does not contain relation columns

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, hasura, typegraphql

Thanks for taking time to review my question, I am executing an introspection query and the result contains tables and columns. As listed in the image below.

```
{
  "name": "tbl_enterprise",
  "kind": "OBJECT",
  "description": "columns and relationships of \"tbl_enterprise\"",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "activity",
      "description": null,
      "type": {
        "name": "bigint",
        "kind": "SCALAR",
        "ofType": null
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "activity_category",
      "description": null,
      "type": {
        "name": "bigint",
        "kind": "SCALAR",
        "ofType": null
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "individual_trader",
      "description": null,
      "type": {
        "name": "Float",
        "kind": "SCALAR",
        "ofType": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is: inside the fields I do have the relation with the table name but there is no information about the which column is related to the table.
As in below you can see there is a field listed in the **tbl_enterprise** table as column which has type of **tbl_person** this is also listed as a column which is very nice but it does not contain which column is the foreign key in the table **tbl_enterprise**

NOT: the relation is one to one and there is a column called individual_trader inside the table tbl_enterprise.

```
{
  "name": "tbl_person",
  "description": "An object relationship",
  "type": {
    "name": "tbl_person",
    "kind": "OBJECT",
    "ofType": null
  }
}
```

Can someone help me if there is the possibility to list the relation with the column.

Comment: please consider copying and pasting those codes instead of pasting in the screenshot. the screenshot is considered as supporting evidence with the code. the textual portion in a code block is easy to index by search engines rather than a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL does not specify *how* relationships are implemented. It makes no assumption about the structure of the underlying database, whether it is relational, document-oriented (ex: MongoDB), a graph db (such as Neo4J), a flat-file, or a series of REST endpoints. Therefore it cannot determine which field(s) might be foreign keys. Indeed in many GraphQL models the foreign keys are not even included in the type model because they are not needed when rendering the objects in a UI.

Comment: Thank you Michel for the answer you are right, I tought it might be possible to also add relation column definitions, but I see it is not.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has use cas for having the relation-column information.

We are using Hasura for our GraphQl server so use meta data endpoints for relation information.

I was using introspection to determine also the relations but it does not give the information.

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/manage-metadata/